# Updating only one function in serverless

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a `serverless.yml` file with 3 functions.

When I run `serverless deploy` it updates all 3 functions, which takes a lot of time.

Is there a way I can update just 1 function without affecting the rest of the stack (i.e., not updating the cloud stack)?

I tried `serverless deploy -f functionA` but it seems to still process and upload the other functions.

```
service: myrestapi
provider:
  name: aws
  region: 'us-east-1'
  runtime: nodejs14.x
functions:
  functionA:
    handler: functions/functionA.handler
    memorySize: 256
  functionB:
    handler: functions/functionB.handler
    memorySize: 128
  functionC:
    handler: functions/functionC.handler
    memorySize: 128
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you think it's deploying the full stack and not only the function ?
Output says it's only deploy's the function A, isn't it ?

```
$ serverless deploy                                                                                                                                         

Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying myrestapi to stage dev (us-east-1)

✔ Service deployed to stack myrestapi-dev (128s)

functions:
  functionA: myrestapi-dev-functionA (30 MB)
  functionB: myrestapi-dev-functionB (30 MB)
  functionC: myrestapi-dev-functionC (30 MB)
```

```
$ serverless deploy -f functionA                                                                                                                            

Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying function functionA to stage dev (us-east-1)

✔ Function code deployed (17s)
Configuration did not change. Configuration update skipped. (17s)
```

Perhaps, you're looking for

```
package:
  individually: true
```

and include only the files needed for your function

```
service: myrestapi
provider:
  name: aws
  region: 'us-east-1'
  runtime: nodejs14.x
package:
  individually: true
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!functions/**'
functions:
  functionA:
    handler: functions/functionA.handler
    memorySize: 256
    package:
      patterns:
        - 'node_modules/node-fetch/**'
        - functions/functionA.js
  functionB:
    handler: functions/functionB.handler
    memorySize: 128
    package:
      patterns:
        - functions/functionB.js
  functionC:
    handler: functions/functionC.handler
    memorySize: 128
    package:
      patterns:
        - 'node_modules/node-fetch/**'
        - functions/functionC.js
```

Comment: That did it. Correct, I wanted a way to upload only the particular package files associated with each function. Thanks!